# Flash blending movie clip with HTML

Tags: html, css, flash, alphablending, blending

Is there a way of having a Flash movie blend into the HTML below it. Like having a flash file with blend mode "Darken" be applied to the content below?

I had a quick look at CSS blend-mode but either I can't figure it out or it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no. Best you can do is set Flash background as transparent:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

but you cant blend flash content with anything else.